# Get values passing a key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, hashmap

I need create a kind of hashmap that i can't do to retrieve some values. This is the situation;

I've got a json with some properties like this one:

```
$scope.getItems = {
        "data": [{
            "label": "first-label",
                "objects": [{
                "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [{
                    "attrname": "Item1",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }, {
                    "attrname": "Item2",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }]
            }],
               "properties": {
                "film:property": "action"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "second-label",
                "objects": [{
                "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [{
                    "attrname": "Item1",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }, {
                    "attrname": "Item2",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }]
            }],
               "properties": {
                "film:property": "action"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "third-label",
                "objects": [{
                "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [{
                    "attrname": "Item1",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }, {
                    "attrname": "Item2",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }]
            }],
               "properties": {
                "film:property": "drama"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "fourth-label",
                "objects": [{
                "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [{
                    "attrname": "Item1",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }, {
                    "attrname": "Item2",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }]
            }],
               "properties": {
                "film:property": "action"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "fifth-label",
                "objects": [{
                "name": "firstObj",
                    "attributes": [{
                    "attrname": "Item1",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }, {
                    "attrname": "Item2",
                        "attrValue": "",
                        "attrType": "text"
                }]
            }],
               "properties": {
                "film:property": "comic"
            }
        }

        ]
    };
```

Ok then, now, what i need is `film:property` and `label`.
As you can see for the film:property "action" we have more that one label and exaclty:

```
- first-label
- second-label
- fourth-label
```

so an hypothetical tree view could be:

```
- action
   - first-label
   - second-label
   - fourth-label

 -drama
   - third-label

 -comic
   -fifth-label
```

I made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/58/ in which there is the same json and a list like this:

```
<ul data-ng-repeat="object in uniqueNames">
        <li ng-click="getLabelByProp(object)"> 
            <a style="cursor:pointer">{{object}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

what i need is when i click over a item get the labels with that property.For example:

click over action and i need to display in somewhere, it's not important where,

```
 - first-label
    - second-label
    - fourth-label
```

and so on for the others. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used filter and map to get your result. 
So first filter for the matching property and then create an array only of labels and finally get unique values:

```
$scope.getLabelByProp = function(property) {
  var filtered = $scope.getItems.data
                .filter(byProperty(property))
                .map(getLabel)
                .filter(isUnique)
  console.log(filtered);
}

function isUnique(item, idx, items) {
  return items.indexOf(item) === idx;
}

function byProperty(property) {
  return function(item, i, items) {
    return item.properties["film:property"] == property
  }
}

function getLabel(n) {
  return n.label;
}
```

I'm not so sure about the uniqueness though.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuqcopm7/60/)

Answer (score 1):

I would map this data into a new structure with `genre` or `category` as top level and the individual films as children

```
[
  {genre: 'action', films:[]},
  {genre: 'drama', films:[]}
]
```

Following loops through all the films and uses the `genre` as key to group the films into respective sub arrays.

```
var tmp = {};

data.forEach(function(item) {
  var genre = item.properties["film:property"];
  if (!tmp[genre]) {
    tmp[genre] = []
  }
  tmp[genre].push(item)
});
```

Once all are in the temp object it is a simple map of those keys to create final scope model

```
$scope.filmCats = Object.keys(tmp).map(function(key) {
  return {
    genre: key,
    films: tmp[key]
  }
});
```

Basic HTML

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in filmCats">
    <h4>{{item.genre}}</h4>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="film in item.films">{{film.label}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="obj in film.objects">{{obj.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Note: You could also do this with the filter `groupBy` that would only require adding a new property name to eaach film that is the value of `"film:property"`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/wr1q8AcrZHdxUjrBGzq2?p=preview)**</kbd>